# Cannot figure out how to create this if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

This is the worlds easiest php if statement ever created, how ever ever I cannot figure out how to do it, in one. Essentially I am having a stumped moment and require the communities help .

This is my function:

```
protected function _traverse_options($name, $type = ''){

    if(isset($this->_options[$name][$type])){
        echo $this->_options[$name][$type];
    }
}
```

The if statement I need is to check for three things:

- If type is not null **but** type is not 'before'
- if type is not null **but** type is not 'after'

I tried doing:

```
if($type != '' && $type != 'before' || $type != '' && $type != 'after'){}
```

How ever that doesn't work.

I know this is simple, but I cannot figure it out? should `||` be `&&` ??

Comment: Doesn't `&&` have a higher precedence than `||`?

Comment: Also, even though `null == ''`, you should use `$type === null` (or `!==`) - it's more exact and less likely to cause strange errors.  For example, what if `$type` really was `''` for some reason?  Or [something else that is considered equal to `''`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This'll do the job:

```
if( $type != '' && $type != 'before' && $type != 'after'){}
```

Answer (score 0):

So any non-empty string that is neither `before` nor `after`.

```
if ('' !== $type && !in_array($type, array('before', 'after')))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly you dont need OR on that statement.
Try with:

```
if (!is_null($type) && strlen($type) > 0 && $type !== 'before' && $type !== 'after') { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses so that you can see what belongs to what.

```
if ($type != null && ($type !== 'before' && $type !== 'after')) {
    // ...
}
```

If you are not careful you can end up with problems, such as in math, where a calculation can give two different results depending on what operation you do first. For example `2*5-10` which can be either `0` or `-10` depending on the order in which you multiply or subtract: `(2*5)-10` or `2*(5-10)`.

You can also make it a little easier to follow by breaking up the logic into variables, making the `if` statement simpler:

```
$notNull = ($type != null);
$notBeforeAndAfter = ($type !== 'before' && $type !== 'after');
if ($notNull && $notBeforeAndAfter) {
    // ...
}
```

If you know exactly what the `$type` variable must contain then you can also use a `switch` statement. It is a lot easier to understand:

```
switch ($type) {
    case 'before':
        echo '$type is "before"';
        break;
    case 'after':
        echo '$type is "after"';
        break;
    // $type is not 'before' or 'after', which means that
    // it is something else which we cannot use...
    default:
        echo '$type is an unknown value. Error maybe?';
        break;
}
```